# Indexing in a nested list: retrieving elements of nested sub-lists

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create a graph of layers where each next layer is densely connected to a previous layer.
Thus I created a nested list for each layer of node labels:

```tex
\def\noderows{{{"M","P","H"},{"L","E","Z"},{"max","mean","all","MIL"},{"M","Q"},{"T","A","E","C","S","SI"},{"mi","mo","se"},{"EN","XGB","MIL"}}}
```

and trying to iterate to connect (existing) nodes from each layer to the next:

```tex
% Iterate over all but the last row
\foreach \rowindex in {0,...,\length} {
  \ifnum\rowindex<\length
    % This is not the last row, so we can do something with it
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextrowindex}{int(\rowindex+1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\row}{\noderows[\rowindex]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextrow}{\noderows[\nextrowindex]}
    \typeout{Row \rowindex: \row}
    \typeout{Next row \nextrowindex: \nextrow}
       \foreach \src in \row {
            \foreach \dst [count=\cn] in \nextrow{
                    \typeout{connection: \src -- \dst}
                       % \edef\connect{\noexpand\typeout{connection: \src{} -- \dst}}%
                       %                     \connect
                    % \draw[->] (\src) -- (\dst);
            }
        }
  \else
    % This is the last row, so we skip it
    \typeout{Skipping last row}
  \fi
}
```

However the rows are not being split into elements:

```
Row 0: {{M}{P}{H}}
Next row 1: {{L}{E}{Z}}
connection: {M}{P}{H}-- {L}{E}{Z}
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Row 1: {{L}{E}{Z}}
Next row 2: {{max}{mean}{all}{MIL}}
connection: {L}{E}{Z}-- {max}{mean}{all}{MIL}
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Row 2: {{max}{mean}{all}{MIL}}
Next row 3: {{M}{Q}}
connection: {max}{mean}{all}{MIL}-- {M}{Q}
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Row 3: {{M}{Q}}
Next row 4: {{T}{A}{E}{C}{S}{SI}}
connection: {M}{Q}-- {T}{A}{E}{C}{S}{SI}
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Row 4: {{T}{A}{E}{C}{S}{SI}}
Next row 5: {{mi}{mo}{se}}
connection: {T}{A}{E}{C}{S}{SI}-- {mi}{mo}{se}
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Row 5: {{mi}{mo}{se}}
Next row 6: {{EN}{XGB}{MIL}}
connection: {mi}{mo}{se}-- {EN}{XGB}{MIL}
```

How can I make it iterate over nested elements here?